# Filtering Outlook items using C#

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook, ms-office

I am using the Office object model to retrieve my calendar items from Outlook. I want to use the Restrict() method to only get today's appointments. I also want to include the single instance of all recurring appointments (i.e. not all recurrences - just those today).

With the below code, I get many (but not all) recurring items like birthdays regardless of the date. I also get various other appointments - but not those for today.

I've tried different formats for the date, including 2013-07-25 00:00:00, without luck. I've researched the net, and tried to copy examples from VBA scripts - no luck.

Appreciate any ideas from others' who have done this.

```
var outlook = new Application();
var calendar = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
DateTime today = DateTime.Today, tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
const string DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
string filter = string.Format("[Start] >= '{0}' AND [Start] < '{1}'", today.ToString(DateFormat), tomorrow.ToString(DateFormat));
var todaysAppointments = calendar.Items.Restrict(filter);
// todaysAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = true;
todaysAppointments.Sort("[Start]");
```

Comment: Have you tried this date format `Mddyy h:mm tt`? From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220350(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and got rather different results. With IncludeRecurrences=true, I just got recurring appointments - like peoples' birthdays. With that set to false, I just get 3 birthdays and nothing else - and those birthdays aren't even this month...

Answer (score 2):

I used the code below and it works perfectly.
I probably use too much 'IncludeRecurrences = false' but it works ;)
I had to do that, or it acts weird (I think 'IncludeRecurrences' compares things differently)

Just put the calendar as first parameter and pDateToRead as the date you want.
(For example)

```
var calendar = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
var calendarItems = GetCalendarItemsOnDate(calendar, DateTime.Today);
```

Actual method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Outlook.AppointmentItem> GetCalendarItemsOnDate(this Outlook.MAPIFolder pCalendarFolder, DateTime pDateToRead)
{
    var filter = "( [Start] >= '" + pDateToRead.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'" + " AND " + "  [End]  < '" +     pDateToRead.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' )";
    pCalendarFolder.Items.IncludeRecurrences = false;
    var outlookCalendarItems = pCalendarFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
    outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = false;

    var allItem = string.Empty;
    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
    {
        if (item.IsRecurring)
        {
            continue;
        }
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.restrict?view=outlook-pia

That document uses other date Format.
I use next filter to check daily for new or edited appointments.

```
        DateTime filterDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-days);
        string filterDateString = filterDate.Day + "/" + filterDate.Month + "/" + filterDate.Year + " 1:00pm";
        string filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" + string.Format(filterDateString, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") + "'";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        NameSpace nameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder calendarFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        Items outlookCalendarItems = calendarFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
        List<AppointmentItem> appsList = new List<AppointmentItem>();
```